# Ruby - how to replace key in a hash by a key from different one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have this hash:

```
CARS = {"Audi"     => 0, 
        "BMW"     => 1,
        ...}
```

And this output from ActiveRecord (`@top_cars`):

```
{1=>18, 0=>17, 3=>13, 5=>10, 2=>5, 4=>1}
```

How do I replace the keys from `@top_cars` by the car names from `CARS`?

Thank you

**EDIT:**
So the desired output would be like `{"BMW"=>18, "Audi"=>17, "Renault"=>13, "Mercedes"=>10, "Ford"=>5, "Porsche"=>1}`

Comment: I rarely downvote questions, but will make an exception here. This question is just sloppy and reflects laziness on the part of writer.  `CARS` being a constant and `@top_cars` an instance variable are irrelevant; local variables would have sufficed. The reference to `ActiveRecord` is also irrelevant. Lastly, why show the desired output without completing  `CARS`? Readers will want to test their solutions, so you are asking them to do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
@top_cars.map {|key, value| [CARS.key(key), value]}.to_h
```

Comment: Depending on the possible values in `CARS`, you may be able to write, `srac = cars.invert; @top_cars.map { |k,v| [srac[k], value] }.to_h`. You've been AWOL.

Answer (score 1):

possible solution:

```
@top_cars.inject({}) {|memo, (key,value)| memo.merge(CARS.key(key) => value)}
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation along with the answer, so the later visitors could also be benefited.

Answer (score 1):

You could merge `cars` with itself:

```
cars = { "Audi"     => 0,
         "Mercedes" => 1,
         "Ford"     => 2,
         "Renault"  => 3,
         "BMW"      => 4,
         "Porsche"  => 5
       }

top_cars = {1=>18, 0=>17, 3=>13, 5=>10, 2=>5, 4=>1}

cars.merge(cars) { |*,n| top_cars[n] }
  #=> {"Audi"=>17, "Mercedes"=>18, "Ford"=>5, "Renault"=>13, "BMW"=>1, "Porsche"=>10}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) where a block is employed to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all the keys.